# Converting strings like document.cookie to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a string similiar to `document.cookie`:

```
var str = 'foo=bar, baz=quux';
```

Converting it into an array is very easy:

```
str = str.split(', ');
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i].split('=');
}
```

It produces something like this:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'quux']]
```

Converting to an object (which would be more appropriate in this case) is harder.

```
str = JSON.parse('{' + str.replace('=', ':') + '}');
```

This produces an object like this, which is invalid:

```
{foo: bar, baz: quux}
```

I want an object like this:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'quux'}
```

**Note**: I've used single quotes in my examples, but when posting your code, if you're using `JSON.parse()`, keep in your mind that it requires double quotes instead of single.

---

### Update

Thanks for everybody. Here's the function I'll use (for future reference):

```
function str_obj(str) {
    str = str.split(', ');
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var cur = str[i].split('=');
        result[cur[0]] = cur[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is this for a real project, or is this an attempt at a golf style question?

Comment: I wouldn't split on `', '` (note the space), but instead split on `','` (no space) and then `trim` the individual parts. This makes it unimportant whether 0, 1, 2, .. spaces or even tabs were used to 'beautify' the input string.

Comment: Sure would be nice if browsers would just implement a object version of cookies. Something like `cookieObject` would be nice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why exactly do you need `JSON.parse` in here? Modifying your arrays example

```js
let str = "foo=bar; baz=quux";

str = str.split('; ');
const result = {};
for (let i in str) {
    const cur = str[i].split('=');
    result[cur[0]] = cur[1];
}


console.log(result);
```

Comment: That produces `['foo=bar', 'baz=quux']`, but I need an **object**.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H No, that produces an object and not array. You can't do `result['foo']` on array.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H - nope, this does exactly what you demanded, as does my very similar example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that the object is in the `result` variable. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this will fail if any of the "cookies" contain the cookie separator; this is probably not a problem, but could be if you use cookies for more complex data (such as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119057).

Answer (score 35):

### The shortest way

```
 document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((prev, current) => {
    const [name, ...value] = current.split('=');
    prev[name] = value.join('=');
    return prev;
  }, {});
```

Comment: Seems like the perfect situation to use reduce.

Comment: A problem with this solution is if the cookie contains "=". This could typically happen if the cookie is base64-encoded. To fix this: `const [name, ...value] = current.split('='); prev[name] = value.join('=')`

Answer (score 5):

*note :* The document.cookie (question headline) is semicolon separated and not comma separated (question) ...

An alternative using `reduce` :

```
var str = 'foo=bar; baz=quux';
var obj = str.split(/[;] */).reduce(function(result, pairStr) {
  var arr = pairStr.split('=');
  if (arr.length === 2) { result[arr[0]] = arr[1]; }
  return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 5):

A way to parse cookies using native methods like [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), avoiding loops and temporary variables.

Parsing `document.cookie`:

```js
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(document.cookie.replace(/; /g, "&")))
```

For the scope of the question (cookies are separated by `,`  and stored in variable `str`)

```js
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(str.replace(/, /g, "&")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Given an array `a` containing your intermediate form:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'quux']]
```

then simply:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
   var tmp = a[i];
   obj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}
```

Comment: It isn't exactly correct, produces `{'foo,bar': ['baz', 'quux']}`.

Comment: corrected - I forgot to use `tmp` instead of `a` in the last line.

Comment: The suggested format is called `entries` (enumerable string-keyed property pairs). A shorter way to convert entries to an object is `Object.fromEntries([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'quux']])`

Comment: @undefined that didn't exist in 2011.

Comment: @Alnitak makes sense, didn't see it's 2011 at the time. I'll still keep the comment here so people know this functionality exists now

Answer (score 2):

To convert it to an object, just do that from the beginning:

```
var obj = {};
str = str.split(', ');
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var tmp = str[i].split('=');
    obj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}
```

Then, if you want JSON out of it:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

parse cookies (IE9+):

```js
document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((result, v) => {
  const k = v.split('=');
  result[k[0]] = k[1];
  return result;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of John Resig's ["Search and don't replace"](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/) method for this sort of thing:

```
var str = 'foo=bar, baz=quux',
    arr = [],
    res = '{';

str.replace(/([^\s,=]+)=([^,]+)(?=,|$)/g, function ($0, key, value) { 
    arr.push('"' + key + '":"' + value + '"');
});

res += arr.join(",") + "}";

alert(res);
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cm6MT/.**

Makes things a lot simpler without the need for JSON support.  Of course, it's just as easy to use the same regular expression with `exec()` or `match()`.

---

Whoops, I thought you wanted to convert to a JSON string, not an object.  In that case, you only need to modify the code slightly:

```
var str = 'foo=bar, baz=quux',
    res = {};

str.replace(/([^\s,=]+)=([^,]+)(?=,|$)/g, function ($0, key, value) { 
    res[key] = value;
});
console.log(res.foo);
//-> "bar"
```

**Working example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/cm6MT/1/**

Comment: Please delete example 1 ! It is confusing because it returns a string ! See http://jsfiddle.net/pjja75hv/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the above solutions fail with the `__gads` cookie that Google sets because it uses a '=' character in the cookie value.

The solution is to use a regular expression instead of calling `split('=')`:

```
document.cookie.split(';').reduce((prev, current) => {
  const [name, value] = current.split(/\s?(.*?)=(.*)/).splice(1, 2);
  prev[name] = value;
  return prev;
}, {});
```

Comment: Or just do `const [name, ...value] = current.split('='); prev[name] = value.join('=')`

Comment: You also need to remove the leading space, as in `prev[name.slice(1)] = value.join('=')`

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty crappy data, as long as its not using ,= this would work on that data

```
var text = 'foo=bar, baz=quux',
    pattern = new RegExp(/\b([^=,]+)=([^=,]+)\b/g),
    obj = {};

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) obj[match[1]] = match[2];

console.dir(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate version of your updated solution that checks for the null/empty string and just returns an empty object and also allows for custom delimiters.

```
function stringToObject(str, delimiter) {
    var result = {};
    if (str && str.length > 0) {
        str = str.split(delimiter || ',');
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            var cur = str[i].split('=');
            result[cur[0]] = cur[1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing that occurred to me, I'll leave it as the original version, but cookies should not be empty otherwise there will be a json parse error

```
JSON.parse(`{"${document.cookie.replace(/=/g,'":"').replace(/; /g,'","')}"}`)
```

fast and reliable version - cookie to object

```
let c=document.cookie.split('; '),i=c.length,o={};
while(i--){let a=c[i].split('=');o[a[0]]=a[1]}
```

and short function for get single cookie

```
getCookie=e=>(e=document.cookie.match(e+'=([^;]+)'),e&&e[1])
```

Comment: maybe `for (let a of c)` would be better. More readable and avoids creating a temporary `i` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCookie(){
   var o=document.cookie.split("; ");
   var r=[{}];
   for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){
      r[o[i].split("=")[0]] = o[i].split("=")[1];
   }
   return r;
}
```

Just call `getCookie()` and it will return all cookies from the current website.
If you have a cookie called 'mycookie' you can run `getCookie()['mycookie'];` and it will return the value of the cookie 'mycookie'.
There is also a One-Line option:

```
function getCookie(){var o=document.cookie.split("; ");var r=[{}];for(var i=0;i<o.length;i++){r[o[i].split("=")[0]] = o[i].split("=")[1];}return r;}
```

This one can be used with the same methods as above.