# JavaScript - Can we set javascript objects in cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to put one javascript object in Cookies but somehow it is getting converted as String object. Is there any way we can set Objects in JavaScript cookies?

Comment: No, you can only store string data. But plain objects can easily converted back and forth to JSON.

Comment: @Bergi: +1 for saying "plain objects".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert Object to JSON before save to cookies, and convert from JSON to Object after get from cookies.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn the object into a JSON string and store it. Then when you read them, turn the string to an Object using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

also, it's better to use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) instead of cookies to store larger data. Both store strings, but cookies are only 4kb while LocalStorage are around 5-10MB.

Answer (score 1):

this function will convert  the object into string use it to stringify the object and then add to cookie.

```
function JSONToString(Obj){

var outStr ='';
for (var prop in Obj) {
    outStr = '{';
    if (Obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if(typeof Obj[prop] == 'object'){
            outStr += JSONToString(Obj[prop]);
        } else {
            outStr += prop + ':' + Obj[prop].toString();
        }
    }  
    outStr += '}';
}
return outStr;
}
```

Comment: Can't I write like this JSON.stringify(<my object>) - this won't convert as a string ?

Comment: [JSON JS](http://www.json.org/js.html) says this var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);

Comment: older browsers like <IE8 dont have a JSON implementations. So best to use a library ex: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/ (use json2.js) to stringify and/or parse strings to objects. The above code tells you what exactly has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON - JavaScript Object Notation. Here's a nice [tutorial on using JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

Long things short: it's a standard of converting any object to a specially formatted text string, and back. So you would store a JSON string in the cookie.

Comment: Not any - if `x` is circular, or has functions, then `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` will not reconstruct to `x`.